# Using R and ggplot to draw separate lines between GPS coordinates

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, maps, ggmap

I am struggling to plot some lines using ggplot in R. I need to connect each pairs (grouped by INDEX). 
The data I am using is:

```
INDEX | LATITUDE | LONGITUDE | VALUE
1       53,071118  -6,063786   40.3
1       53,076478  -6,067592   40.3
2       53,071118  -6,063786   60.7
2       53,099204  -6,067235   60.7
```

And the code:

```
require(ggmap);
require(ggplot2);
options(warn=-1)

mydata = read.delim2("mydata.csv", TRUE, "\t")
df=as.data.frame(mydata)

City="Dublin, Ireland"

baseMap = get_map(location = City, zoom = 11, maptype = "terrain")
map <- ggmap(baseMap) +
  geom_path(aes(x=LONGITUDE, y=LATITUDE, group=INDEX), data=df, alpha=0.2)
map
```

On the last two lines the error is "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale".
How can I overcome that?

Edit:
I inserted

```
df$LATITUDE=as.numeric(as.character(df$LATITUDE))
df$LONGITUDE=as.numeric(as.character(df$LONGITUDE))
df$INDEX=as.numeric(as.character(df$INDEX))
```

and it started working. Bear in mind that the coordinates had to be with dots, not commas.
[image: the lines are connected to each other]

Comment: I think you want to check class in df. `str(df)` will tell you classes. You probably have factor although ggplot is expecting numeric.

Comment: Thanks, that was the case! i added df$LATITUDE=as.numeric(df$LATITUDE)
df$LONGITUDE=as.numeric(df$LONGITUDE)
df$INDEX=as.numeric(df$INDEX) to the code and now it runs. Now i have to see why nothing gets drawn to the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed adding

```
df$LATITUDE=as.numeric(as.character(df$LATITUDE))
df$LONGITUDE=as.numeric(as.character(df$LONGITUDE))
df$INDEX=as.numeric(as.character(df$INDEX))
```

and replacing ',' in the data with '.'